# How do I (and do I even want to) delete outdated versions of the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, kernel

I notice that GRUB (or is it GRUB2?) asks which version of Linux I'd like to boot, and outdated versions of the kernel are listed. How do I remove these and their associated files to save disk space? Since I'm new to Linux, is there any reason why I shouldn't remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out, it says it all: [Link](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2007/10/17/remove-ubuntu-kernels-you-dont-need/)

Comment: To summarize what's found at the link: Use the Synaptic package manager to uninstall the old kernels.

Comment: No, it also explains why old kernels are not automatically deleted...